# capture video from screen for stream

Tags: windows, video-streaming, screen-capture

i am looking for differnt solutions to capture video stream from monitor screen and send it to vidoestreaming server to broadcast in web. it must occuring in "live".

i'd not like to use external services like "procaster" for broad.

OS: Windows.

it will be great to know the ideas and expirience people have to accomplish that.

Thanks all.

Comment: Windows, i just have added this information in question

Answer (score 5):

Recently, I build a GoLang project called [ScreenStreamer](https://github.com/fiefdx/ScreenStreamer), is a tool to stream current active window or full screen (Linux's or Windows's) to other device, like phone or another PC, as MJPEG over http or FLV over rtmp, it's very realtime (delay < 100ms). It works on Windows and Linux.

After building it, you can run it as:

```
# enter the project root directory
cd ./src/ScreenStreamer
# run it
./mjpeg or .\mjpeg.exe
# use a web browser or other video player, open http://host:port/mjpeg

./rtmp or .\rtmp.exe
# use a video player, open rtmp://host:port/live/screen
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows SDK includes [Push Source Filters Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which in turn contains `CPushSourceDesktop` filter/class.

> CPushSourceDesktop: Copy of current desktop image (GDI only)

It captures desktop image and pushes it into DirectShow pipeline. From there on you can process it using video compression codec and stream it to remote location. A decent screen image compression codec is included with Windows Media subsystem, network streaming will have to be a custom or third party component. Alternatively, it is possible to make the capture class a virtual camera and have Windows Media Encoder broadcast it (or, it already has a simila feature built in).

**Alternatively**, you can check VNC (or one of the clones) source code and see how it hooks windows and captures image updates, then compresses them and makes it available for remote applications.

Note that you will have to specifically capture non-GDI images (such as coming from video/gaming applications, which use hardware acceleration and non-RGB surffaces).

Comment: I can not capture video games in both cases ?

Comment: It depends, there are certain scenarios when captured image is just blackness. I believe it is OS and hardware dependent. Anyway, both VNC and WME are capable to capture from screen out of the box, so you can check them against gaming apps without even writing any code.